# aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host :443 ssl:default [The semaphore timeout period has expired]

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, python-asyncio, semaphore

I use asyncio and aiohttp in my code, and it runs perfectly fine on my work laptop. However, when I run it on my virtual machine from my work laptop, I run into this error "The semaphore timeout period has expired" but I do not have semaphore in my code at all. Is this a network firewall issue? There is a proxy attached to the network settings and the VM is on windows 10.